# linux/if_packet.h on Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, port, compatibility

I want to compile/port a linux commandline tool to OSX, but I get this error

```
 tcptable.h:26:29: error: linux/if_packet.h: No such file or directory
 tcptable.h:27:28: error: linux/if_ether.h: No such file or directory
 tcptable.h:30:27: error: linux/if_fddi.h: No such file or directory
 tcptable.h:31:25: error: linux/if_tr.h: No such file or directory
```

The `if_*` header files a not avaiable on my OSX machine, so I tried to find an alternative for that lib. Unfortunately I don't found anything. Is there some compatibility lib or something that I can use to compile this code?

Comment: If it's for decoding packets just copy from Linux.  However I suspect there may be more fundamental non-portability issues.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, there are a lot more incompatibilities which are not easy to fix. :(

Comment: This should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com